translating ethnos to gens in John 11:50
Given that the Greek ethnos typically mean ethnic groups of people, why did the Vulgate translate it to gens in this verse?
If I am reading the verse correctly (this is a big assumption) should it say "... one man should die instead of all the people of Israel"?

The most authoritative translation of the Latin vulgate is the Douay-Rheims which has this for John 11:50 -

Neither do you consider that it is expedient for you that one man
should die for the people, and that the whole nation perish not.

Note that "gens" is translated by "nation" - a perfectly valid translation of both the Latin "gens" and the Greek ἔθνος (ethnos).

Thanks for this response...  It is a great explanation.

Delitzsch, who predated modern Hebrew, translated ἔθνος with גּוֹי, the primary word ἔθνος translates in the Septuagint.  In Genesis 12:2 God promised to make Abraham a great nation (גֹ֣וי גָּדֹ֔ול), but גֹ֣וי is also what Jews can gentiles.  Nation and gentile are the same word in Hebrew.  The meaning depends on the context.  Latin gen apparently has the same variation in meaning as these words.  Jerome to Hebrew well, not only Greek.
References

gens, gentis, f. [root GEN, gigno, that which belongs together by birth or descent], a race or clan, embracing several families united together by a common name and by certain religious rites; orig. only patrician, but, after the granting of the connubium between patricians and plebeians, also plebeian (syn.: familia, stirps, genus; natio, populus).... --
Lewis, C. T., & Short, C. (1891). In Harpers’ Latin Dictionary (p. 808). Harper & Brothers; Clarendon Press.


gēns, gentis, f
GEN-, a race, clan, house (of families having a name and certain religious rites in common): Minucia: clarissima Corneliorum, S.: patres maiorum gentium: minorum gentium patres, L.: gent is enuptio, the right of marrying out of her gens, L.: periurus, sine gente, i. e. of no family, H.: maiorum gentium di, of the highest rank: dii minorum gentium, of the inferior orders: maiorum gentium Stoicus, i. e. eminent.—A descendant, offspring, representative: deūm gens, Aenea, V.; cf. heroës, deūm gens, Ct.: (equos) in spem submittere gentis, V.—A tribe, brood, crew: ista Clodiana.—A race, species, breed: human<*>, C., H.: haec (i. e. volpes), O.—A race, tribe, people: eiusdem gentis (esse): Suebi, quorum non una gens, Ta.: exterae gentes: exercitus compositus ex variis gentibus, S.: Nerviorum, Cs.: oppidum Thessaliae, quae gens miserat, etc., community, Cs.: omnes eius gentis cives, N.: ius gentium: ubicumque terrarum et gentium, in the world: ubinam gentium sumus? on earth: nusquam gentium, T.: tu autem longe gentium, far away in the world: minime gentium, by no means, T.—Plur, foreign nations, foreigners: duretque gentibus amor nostri, Ta.—A region, country: qui Cataoniam tenebat: quae gens iacet, etc.
--
Lewis, C. T. (1890). In An Elementary Latin Dictionary. American Book Company.

Figure 1. Hebrew words ἔθνος translates in the LXX (generated with Logos Bible Software)

Figure 2. Senses of ἔθνος in the New Testament (generated with Logos Bible Software)


אַף לֹא־תָבִינוּ כִּי טוֹב לָנוּ מוּת אִישׁ אֶחָד בְּעַד הַגּוֹי מֵאֲבֹד הָעָם כֻּלּוֹ׃
(John 11:50, Delitzsch Hebrew New Testament).


That was my gut feeling on this word... thank you for the data!!!
